# How to create application to show Wifi Signal Strength in C#?

Tags: c#, wifi

I'm trying to create a application to show wifi signal strength in C#
i can get signal strength , but i want my app will check signal strength every second !
i use backgroundworker, but it's not work.
my way to get signal strength:

```
Process proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "netsh.exe",
                Arguments = "wlan show interfaces",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        proc.Start();
        string line;
        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            if (line.Contains("Signal"))
            {
              label1.Text = line.Split(':')[1];  
            }
        }
```

Comment: You may use a timer, instead of a backgroundworker

Comment: Always describe "but it's not work". Is there an exception, wrong output, ... ?

Comment: Yop, i try to put a while loop into DoWork Event and. . . it's worked !!
http://i.imgur.com/IUc3PvJ.png